# Angular SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I run this....

```
var url = "http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=xxx&apiKey=xxx&minorRev=30&currencyCode=AUD";
        $http.jsonp(url)
            .then(function(mycallback){
                $scope.md = mycallback;
                var mydata = mycallback.data; 
                console.log(mydata);            
        });
```

I get: this error SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

If I change it to get:

```
 var url = "http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=xxx&apiKey=xxx&minorRev=30&currencyCode=AUD";
        $http.get(url)
            .then(function(mycallback){
                $scope.md = mycallback;
                var mydata = mycallback.data; 
                console.log(mydata);            
        });
```

I get this error SyntaxError:JSON.parse.unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the json data

If I put callback=JSON_CALLBACK at the end it makes no difference. Either which way I can't console.log this endpoint. So stressful.

I have tried other endpoints such as these and these work correctly
var url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
var url = "http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php";

[image]

[image: It call has succeeded and retruned on the right]

Comment: Exactly what line does your error occur on? The `console.log` call, or before that?  Do you have `JSON_CALLBACK` defined?  Can we see the source of that function?

Comment: It is before that and it is referring to to json file....I don't have JSON_CALLBACK defined

Comment: If I make a standard get getquest withou jsonp I get this error SyntaxError:JSON.parse.unexpedcted end of data at line 1 column 1 of the jason data

Comment: What does the data coming back from the ean.com API look like if you access it directly from the browser?

The fact that you tried a few example APIs and they returned proper JSON and worked correctly makes me think it could be an issue with the API you are accessing... it may not be returning data in the proper format.

Comment: Thats what I thought also. I contacted them and they ran it from their end and said it was fine. I have also run the URL in Advanced REST client chrome extension and it returns a valid response

Comment: I copied the response from the screenshot into a json validator and it is valid

Answer (score 0):

Please try encoding the URI before passing it to the request. This seems to be the only issue here as we need to encode special characters inside your query string here.

`url = encodeURI(url)`

Comment: Tried this and the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

`var url = 'url' + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'` 
This will solve the issue